# Pyshark install continue to fail Visual C++ requirement though build tools installed.

Tags: python-3.x, pyshark

I'm trying to install pyshark on a Win10 machine. I'm running Python3.6. I continually get the following error, even though I have installed MS C++ Redistributables and MS Build Tools 2015.

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

[image: Installs]

Answer (score 0):

I have read a little about this problem.
https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/
For python3, you can install build tools 2017 from the official microsoft website.

The link for the build tools is given below -
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159

It's just a 25M file and should consume around 200MB of your Hard disk

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Your answer suggests install build tools 2017, but the link is to 2015. You will note that I have 2015 installed. However, installing build tools for 2017 seems to have worked. If you change your link to https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15 , I will mark it as the answer.